# C# Regex DataAnnotations not detect end line

Tags: c#, regex, entity-framework-core

I want this Regex in my model check end line "-AR" or "-UY" but not working

```
[StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "The field must have between {2} y {1} characters", MinimumLength = 3)]
[RegularExpression(@"(-AR$)|{-UY$}", ErrorMessage = "Must have the regional parameter. Argentina:'-AR' ,Uruguay:'-UY'")]
public string Key { get; set; }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, replace `{}` with `()`?

```
[RegularExpression(@"(-AR$)|(-UY$)", ErrorMessage = "Must have the regional parameter. Argentina:'-AR' ,Uruguay:'-UY'")]
```